# Strip the word and find its length

Tags: linux, cpu-word, strip

I am new to linux.

I want to get the word `abc` from the `abc-d023-1234` and get the length of the stripped word(abc)

```
$serverenvicheck =abc-d023-1234
stripfirstword= 'echo  $serverenvicheck | cut -d '-' f -1'

sstripfirstword = awk '{print substr($0,1,4)|' $stripfirstword
```

Output

```
./test.sh: line 23: echo  $serverenvicheck | cut -d - f -1: command not found
./test.sh: line 25: sstripfirstword: command not found
stripped firstword
```

How to strip the word as well as to find its length?

```
./test.sh: line 23: echo  $serverenvicheck | cut -d - f -1: command not found
./test.sh: line 25: stripfirstword: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignments to variables in shell scripts take the form of

```
var="some values"
```

Note that there is no space surrounding the `=` char.

The most efficient solution to your problem is

```
serverenvicheck="abc-d023-1234"
stripfirstword="${serverenvicheck%%-*}"
echo "$stripfirstword"

echo  "length of \$stripfirstword 's value is ${#stripfirstword}"
```

**output**

```
abc
```

The magic happens with the shell's parameter modification feature found in

```
echo ${var%%-*}
```

which mean "match back from the right side of the variable value, the longest string that matches `-*`"  (using shell reg ex, where `*` is equivalent to most languages' regex of `.*`).

If you use echo `${var%-*}` you'll match from the right the shortest match, and in your case you would get `abc-d023`.

IHTH